# Warning against bad advice deleted, but not the bad advice itself

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

In the question [How to address Java Error with deprecated API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59474744/7509065), someone left [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474744/how-to-address-java-error-with-deprecated-api#comment105127921_59474744) suggesting that the asker simply disable the messages for the warnings she's asking for help with rather, than them telling her how to make the messages more helpful so she could try to understand and fix them.

Since this is [bad advice](http://thecodelesscode.com/case/115), I left a comment myself to call it out as such.

However, when I looked at the question today, my comment was deleted but his is still there. Why did this happen?

Comment: Depending on the specific content of your comment, it could simply had been flagged for one reason or another. Impossible to guess without the actual copy. The other comment, correct or incorrect, is not really flag-worthy.

Comment: It may have been bad advice, but not, I think, for the reason you allude to with the linked parable about suppressing warnings. If I'm understanding correctly it, the asker is trying to follow a tutorial from 2001 about creating [Java applets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet) to run on web pages - a feature that browser vendors starting removing outright from browsers in 2013 and is thus now deprecated in Java. If she wants to proceed, she will have no choice but to ignore the warnings, because there is no "fix" she can apply to her code. But she should probably buy a newer book.

Comment: (Please do correct me if I've misunderstood - I'm not a Java man.)

Answer (score 14):

I can assure you that there is no conspiracy by the moderators to promulgate bad advice on Stack Overflow. <strike>Somebody</strike> A bot just flagged your comment as "unfriendly or unkind", and the moderator who reviewed the flag deleted it.

Your comment was the following:

> @SunilDabburi That's some of the worst advice I've ever heard. You NEVER turn off warnings without knowing why they're there.

Yeah. It wasn't me who deleted it, but I'm not exactly going to wring my hands about that one.

My suggestion would be to find a more constructive way of expressing disagreement. Otherwise, you risk having your comments deleted.

Aside from being unnecessarily hostile, your comment really didn't convey information. It wasn't much more useful than "you're wrong!" If you hope to convince someone, it helps to make actual arguments. Otherwise, you're just shouting into the wind.